# Get next row in peewee

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I creating blog using Flask and peewee

this is the sample query to get the current post using `url`

```
total_data = wired_model.EN.select().order_by(wired_model.EN.id.desc())
post = total_data.where(wired_model.EN.url == url).get()
```

I am using `total_data` to get the recent posts, now I want to show a link to next post and the previous post in the current post, is there a simple way to do it in peewee like `next_row()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "offset":

```
.limit(1).offset(1)
```